# Minikube installation on Azure VM - NV6(promo)

Tags: azure, nested, virtual-machine, virtualization, minikube

I am working onto install Minikube on Azure VM - Ubuntu - NV6. 
I installed KVM2 driver, now as mentioned in the [document](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) it is required t have VT-x/AMD-v virtualization enabled in BIOS .

Question - How do i know if Azure VM - NV6 supports VT-x/AMD-v virtualization ? If it not by default, how can i enable it?

I also installed Minikube using curl, but it throws error if i try to start Minikube.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are an on going issue on GitHub, will track it there.

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4730#issue-466395657
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4804#issue-469709296

Thanks